# How to make the open in the Modal component false?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, next.js

I've been using NextJS and sometimes, I'm not sure, if it's about React missconception or the NextJS Framework I needed to understand better to make some simple things work!

Bellow, I have the code which should set false next time I press (F5) in the client side. I'm using NextJS!

```
import { Modal } from "@mui/material";
import React, { useState } from "react";

const LangModal = () => {
    const [open, setOpen] = useState(true);
    const handleModal = () => {
        setOpen(false);
        console.log("[Agora o Model é false]", open);
};

return (
    <Modal open={open} onClick={() => handleModal()}>
        <div>
            <h2> Simple React Modal</h2>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi accumsan odio enim, non pharetra est ultrices et.</p>
        </div>
    </Modal>
  );
};
export default LangModal;
```

Please, could you help me guys???

Comment: you are initialising open to true, so each time you will refresh the page it should display the modal, would you plz explain in which case you want to display the modal ?

Comment: Only the first time! I would put it in the useEffect! However, how could I set false, after the  Modal is already opened?

Comment: It would be better than to pass the handleModal and the open state in the props.
Add a button (x) to close the modal.

Comment: try this solution 
const Parent = () => {
  const [isModalOpen, setModalOpen] = useState(true);

  <ModalComponent open={isModalOpen} handleModal={()=>setModalOpen(!isModalOpen)} />
}

const ModalComponent = ({open, handleModal}) => {
  <Modal open={open}>
    <button onClick={handleModal}>x</button>
    ...
  </Modal>
}

Comment: Is this props called getStaticProps? 
Which props do you mean! Please! I'm new to it and still a little confused!

Comment: Ok, I'll try it out! Thank you so much @FdM

Comment: the props is what you passed from the parent component to the child , if you have any question about the solution above just ask.

Comment: Hi, it Holly takes all sense. I got what you meant! ^^
Unhappely, I got a error => "TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'hasOwnProperty')"

Comment: I'll have a look at this one now. But, I believe you opened my eyes. Thank you loads @FdM

Comment: if you still have the error, paste your code here and we will look to it together

Comment: Now, it's ok! Awesome! ^^